# Automated testing of routes using Python Bottle framework

Tags: python, testing, routes, bottle

I would like to build an automated way of testing all the routes in my Python/Bottle web application, as I currently have about 100 routes.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend [WebTest](http://webtest.pythonpaste.org/en/latest/); it's fully featured and very easy to use. Here's a complete working example that demonstrates a simple test:

```
from bottle import Bottle, response
from webtest import TestApp

# the real webapp
app = Bottle()


@app.route('/rest/<name>')
def root(name):
    '''Simple example to demonstrate how to test Bottle routes'''
    response.content_type = 'text/plain'
    return ['you requested "{}"'.format(name)]


def test_root():
    '''Test GET /'''

    # wrap the real app in a TestApp object
    test_app = TestApp(app)

    # simulate a call (HTTP GET)
    resp = test_app.get('/rest/roger')

    # validate the response
    assert resp.body == 'you requested "roger"'
    assert resp.content_type == 'text/plain'


# run the test
test_root()
```

Comment: Do I have to running WSGI server in this case? Currently, I am using `unittest` + `bottle` without running WSGI server. I don't know how to get dynamic part of a route into a view.

Comment: No, you don't need a server. WebTest is in place of a server.

Answer (score 0):

Bottle's creator [recommends](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/recipes.html#functional-testing-bottle-applications) using [WebTest](http://webtest.pythonpaste.org/en/latest/), which is a framework specifically designed for unit testing Python WSGI applications.

Additionally, there is also [Boddle](https://github.com/keredson/boddle), a testing tool specifically for Bottle. I have not used this software myself, so I cannot speak to how well it works, however, as of the time of this answer posting, it appears to be actively maintained.

I recommend looking at one or both of those and just giving it a try. If you find yourself with further questions about how to properly integrate with one of them, post another question.

Good luck!